# Will a force be exerted on a wire NOT carrying current in a VARYING magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism

I know that if a wire is carrying current, the force is F= iBl sinc

But what if the wire does not have current, and rather the magnetic field around it varies. Will there still be a force? If so, what will be it's magnitude.

You may consider magnetic field direction as required to get a value of force if possible.

Note: This is not repeated question. Other similar questions are regarding wires carrying current. Mine is for wires with no current.

Comment: You gave the answer yourself: if I=0 the force is 0 no matter which direction B

Comment: @trula But does variation of B cause a force? That is my question.

Comment: No, not in a straight wire, The area B goes through has to change.

Comment: Just as I said.:no force

Answer (score 0):

If there is no current there is no force. However, a changing magnetic field will induce a current (causing there to be a force) in the wire if allowed.

Comment: What current and do you mean with "if allowed"